# Google Place API Autocomplete Service in Android Application

Tags: android, autocomplete

How can I  do as in this example ?

[image]

Comment: Take a look at http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-autocompletetextview-with-google-places-autocomplete-api/

Comment: did your problem got resolve?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this async task in your activity.

```
public class Async extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    String resp = "";
    Double lat;
    Double lng;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            resp = downloadUrl(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_DETAILS + OUT_JSON
                    + "?key=" + API_KEY + "&reference=" + arg0[0]
                    + "&sensor=false");

            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(resp.toString());
            JSONObject jObj = jsonObj.getJSONObject("result");
            JSONObject jObj2 = jObj.getJSONObject("geometry");
            JSONObject jObj3 = jObj2.getJSONObject("location");
            lat = jObj3.getDouble("lat");
            lng = jObj3.getDouble("lng");

            Log.e("lat", "" + lat);
            Log.e("lng", "" + lng);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.e("response---->", resp);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Location loc = new Location("");
        loc.setLatitude(lat);
        loc.setLongitude(lng);
        updateCurrentMarker(loc);
        changeCamera(getLastCameraUpdate(loc));
        marker.setDraggable(true);
        // btn_save.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);

        // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Connecting to url
        urlConnection.connect();

        // Reading data from url
        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                iStream));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }

        data = sb.toString();

        br.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
    } finally {
        iStream.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return data;
}

private ArrayList<LocationAutoCompleteModel> autocomplete(String input) {
    ArrayList<LocationAutoCompleteModel> resultList = null;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE
                + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
        sb.append("?sensor=false&key=" + API_KEY);
        // sb.append("&components=country:uk");
        sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));

        URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

        // Load the results into a StringBuilder
        int read;
        char[] buff = new char[1024];
        while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
            jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
        return resultList;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to Places API", e);
        return resultList;
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }

    try {
        // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
        JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");

        // Extract the Place descriptions from the results
        resultList = new ArrayList<LocationAutoCompleteModel>(
                predsJsonArray.length());
        for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
            LocationAutoCompleteModel lm = new LocationAutoCompleteModel();
            lm.setDesc(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString(
                    "description"));
            lm.setRef(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                    .getString("reference"));
            resultList.add(lm);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot process JSON results", e);
    }

    return resultList;
}

public class PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
        implements Filterable {

    public PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return resultList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int index) {
        return resultList.get(index).getDesc();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null) {
                    // Retrieve the autocomplete results.
                    resultList = autocomplete(constraint.toString());
                    Log.e("ExampleApplication getFilter",
                            "" + constraint.toString());

                    // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                    filterResults.values = resultList;
                    filterResults.count = resultList.size();
                }
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                          FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }
        };
        return filter;
    }
}
```

And call like this

```
AutoCompleteTextView autoCompView = (AutoCompleteTextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.searchLocation);
        autoCompView.setThreshold(3);
        autoCompView.setAdapter(new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1));
        autoCompView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                                    long arg3) {

                String PARAMETERS = resultList.get(arg2).getRef();
                Log.e("ref string", PARAMETERS);
                new Async().execute("" + PARAMETERS);
            }
        });
```